# Why didn't Missandei push her off the platform?

Tags: game-of-thrones

When Cersei leaned in for the talk Missandei could have easily thrown her off the platform to her death. Instead she decided to be dramatic and feed into Daenerys's worst impulses.

There were no restraints on her arm or legs. She was not even kneeling. It was the easiest thing to do but she did not.

Why?

Comment: Last words would be "RUN" and then they run away from the ballistae and the arrows.

Comment: "There are no restraints on her arms or legs" Iron shackles do tend to restrain arm movements to a good extent. Missandei isn't exactly swole.

Comment: She's also from <s>Alderaan</s> Naath, the Isle of butterflies, and has received zero combat training.

Comment: Because then we'd only get 4 episodes in Season 8 and they needed to shoot more.

Comment: To double down on what @Paul said, Naath is renowned for its peaceful ways https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Naath. Extreme pacifism to the max.

Comment: I think that she was rather lightly bound because it's a bit more palatable for the viewers. If this were real life, she would have been bound considerably more. That's the trade-off: you get to watch a show where prisoners occasionally preserve their familiar dress code and visual character, and are not fully bound by ropes or chains - and you accept that they cannot function freely, as though they were.

Comment: **1. To what end?**. She was going to die anyway, better to show the people Cersei's ways. Chucking Cersei off the ramparts, to her death, would have provoked hate from the people of King's Landing. Besides, this would have been followed by an all out assault from Dany's crew, which is going to happen anyway.

Comment: **2. It was logistically improbable**. Missandei was [shackled](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211790/21267), surrounded and faced a barrier in front of her. Besides, what makes you think she's strong enough to overpower Cersei?

Answer (score 8):

You're wrong.  Her hands are in irons.

[image: it's plainly visible in like 30 different shots]

Her feet don't appear to be shackled, either to the manacles or otherwise, which is a little odd.  But still, your assumptions are flawed, as you can clearly see the manacles in this and many other shots in the scene.

Comment: Shackles or no shackles, she's still capable of pushing or pulling.

Comment: @Brad Yes, which is part of why a lack of leg irons that are connected to the manacles is a bit surprising.  It'd be much harder to pull off the desired maneuver with your legs and arms mutually constrained in their range of motion.  But point remains the OP was supposing she was completely unconstrained, which is false.

Comment: They also drew attention to it with Cersei's comment "So much for the breaker of chains" at the start of this scene, before panning to a close-up of the shackles before zooming out to reveal who it was.

Answer (score 3):

Shackles would have made it easier to grab Cersei in a bear hug and jump together..

I understand that she is from an island of pacifists but at that point she has enough genre awareness to choose "burn them all" as her last words. So (1) she knows she is about to die, and (2) she is belligerent enough to ask Dany to avenge her. Yet, she doesn't take Cersei with her.

I guess she is also aware that the season needs more drama before Cersei is dead.

Comment: Dracarys means "dragonfire".

Comment: I know, but the choice before Dany was repeatedly stated as whether to burn the city to get to Cersei or try a less crispy solution, and her last words were shown as a dying advisor's advice on that choice.

Comment: Human brains don't really work like this.  We forget because we're used to the media pumping out stories of people doing heroically suicidal things.  But a powerful chunk of your brain is pretty much solely dedicated to stopping you from committing suicide in any form.  It takes a lot to override it, and people, like Missandei, who haven't constantly fought with their survival instinct in order to override it, aren't going to simply try to kill themselves just because it "logically" make sense because it kills someone else and they were gonna die anyway.